# CDF of positively correlated Gaussians

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, correlation

Suppose $X,Y$ are two positively correlated Gaussians with zero mean and unit variance. Is it the case that for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$
\Pr[X \leq a, Y \leq b] \geq \Pr[X \leq a] \Pr[Y \leq b]?
$$

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298422/conditional-probability-of-correlated-gaussians (not the same, but related)

Comment: Did my answer settle the question, or is it falling short?

Comment: Yes, it seems to work! Pitt's paper uses a slightly different definition ($f,g$ have to be monotone nondecreasing rather than both monotone in the same direction), but I don't think it makes any difference (we can consider $-f,-g$ instead).

Comment: One application is proving the two-function Borell's theorem from the Mossel-Neeman version, though Ryan O'Donnell has a different approach (for the one-function version).

Comment: Nice! Does it give a simpler proof? (Knowing Ryan's proofs, I wonder if it's even possible)

Comment: It gives a more direct proof. It's a few lines either way. Using M-N's notation, what you showed is $ab \leq J(a,b)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be overkill, but I believe this follows from the fact that for Gaussians, positive (resp. negative) association is equivalent to positive (resp. negative) correlation [1], along with the definition of positive association [2] *(apply it to $f = \mathbf{1}_{(-\infty,a]}$ and $g= \mathbf{1}_{(-\infty,b]}$)*.

---

[1] Pitt, Loren D. *Positively Correlated Normal Variables are Associated.* Ann. Probab. 10 (1982), no. 2, 496—499. doi:10.1214/aop/1176993872. https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1176993872

[2] Dubhashi, Devdatt, and Desh Ranjan. *Balls and bins: A study in negative dependence.* Random Structures & Algorithms 13.2 (1998): 99—124.
https://www.brics.dk/RS/96/25/BRICS-RS-96-25.pdf